# Maven Jenkins Ubuntu Springboot NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, maven, ubuntu, jenkins

When I run `mvn clean install` on my `MacOS`, then run the `spring boot application jar`, it works fine, however when `Jenkins` on `Ubuntu` builds the `jar`, even if I start it on my mac, I get `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` and my application context fails. I inspected the jars inner contents and everything matches. What could explain this?

Here is the MANIFEST file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: jenkins
Start-Class: com.company.project.Application
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.3.1.RELEASE
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_45
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

The JDK and Maven versions are the same. The only difference is that I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.